# Extracting unique values with SQL

Tags: python, sql, bash, hive, duplicates

I'm new to SQL and would greatly appreciate your help with extracting data from a hive table. The table contains two relevant columns: `host` and `url`.  The `url` column has a lot of  duplicates and similar urls redirecting to the same page, in the following format:

```
https://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics/
https://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics
http://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics/
http://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics
```

Example of host format:

```
https://www.cnn.com/
http://www.cnn.com/
```

I need a query to extract unique urls with preference of `https` version over `http` and url with trailing slash over url without trailing slash, when available. So for the example above the result should be:

`https://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics/`

A simple bash or python script to do the same for local files would be extremely helpful, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for Hive. Use `row_number()` for removing duplicates. See how `protocol_key` and `path_key` are calculated, they are used in the `row_number() partition by` clause:

```
with your_data as (--use your table instead of this
select stack( 4,
'https://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics/',
'https://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics',
'http://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics/',
'http://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics') as url
) --your table

select url from
(
select s.url, --s.protocol, s.protocol_key, s.host, s.path, s.path_key, --columns for debugging
       row_number() over(partition by s.protocol_key, s.host, s.path_key order by s.protocol desc, s.path desc) rn --https and path with/ are preferred
from       
(--parse url
select t.url, s.protocol, s.host, s.path, regexp_replace(s.path,'/$','') as path_key, regexp_replace(s.protocol,'s$','') as protocol_key
  from your_data t
       lateral view parse_url_tuple(url, 'PROTOCOL','HOST', 'PATH')s as protocol, host, path
)s)s where rn = 1
;
```

Result:

```
https://www.cnn.com/2019/09/20/politics/
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to modify it for my table, but it worked for my case.